# django simple debugging gives strange result

Tags: django

I experience something interesting in my project, I'm using Oracle as db. Inside js when I call home view function strange things happen. How can it happen?

## js

```
setInterval(function() {
    var div = document.querySelector("#counter");
    var count = div.textContent * 1 - 1;
    div.textContent = count;
    if (count <= 0) {
        window.location.href="{% url 'home' %}";
    }
}, 1000);
```

## home

```
def home(request):
# First check IP address
if request.user == AnonymousUser():
    ip_address  = get_ip_address(request)
    user_logged = login_ip_address(request,ip_address,request.user)

if request.user.is_authenticated:
    print "1"
    getNotifications(request)
    print "2"
    requests = getRequests(request)
    print "3"
    user_categories_names = getUserCategories(request)
    print "4"
    chart = []

    if requests:
        print "5"
        openR = requests.filter(status="open").count()
        print "6"
        closedR = requests.filter(status="closed").count()
        print "7"
        lockedR = requests.filter(status__contains="lock").count()
        print "8"
        if openR>0 or closedR>0 or lockedR>0:
            print "9"
            chart=[openR,closedR,lockedR]
            print "10"
        else:
            print "11"
            deletedR = requests.filter(status="deleted").count()
            chart=[deletedR]
    #allCategoryRequests = getAllCategoryRequests(request,user_categories_requests)

    #requests = list(chain(sentRequestResult, tagRequests, parentRequestResult))
    print "12"
    data = {'requests':requests,'catNames':user_categories_names,'chart':chart,'activeCategory':'taggedRequests'}
    template = "home.html"
    print "13"
    #pdb.set_trace()
    return render(request,template,data)
    print "14"
else:
    print "15"
    return HttpResponseRedirect('accounts/login')
```

## Output

1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
2
3
1
1
4
5
2
3
6
7
4
8
5
9
10
12
13
6
1
7
8
9
10
12
13
2
3
2
3
4
1
2
3
4
5
Killed: 9

Comment: What is strange about it? [ask]

Comment: output doesnt say anything to you ?

Comment: Well it does seem strange that the word "killed" appears randomly out of no where when your code block doesn't mention it at all but how is anyone supposed to know what is normal and what isnt?

Comment: I mentioned it is Oracle DB, oracle "kills" process.

Comment: Sayse, I see you also know 'how to edit comment', I advice you to be polite. Before posting question, I know the problem in which area. So you should learn something before commenting as well.

Comment: I edited my comment because I realised it had some stuff in it that wasn't fully constructive, but your questions quality still isn't my responsibility. [mcve]... If you wish to discuss about how this question could have been improved more, feel free to raise a question on [meta]

Answer (score 2):

the problem was in js, it was sending multiple redirection. So it should be if (count == 0).